# On alternative training in case you can not practice a violin for a long time

Tags: violin

On alternative training in case you can not practice a violin for a long time?

I have been playing the violin for about 25 years.
I am doing it as a hobby, but I play it at least once every two days on weekdays.

This time, overseas business trips for one year are decided, during that time you will not be able to practice at all.
(It is impossible to play in a business trip destination)
I think that my arm will fall considerably if I do not touch musical instruments for a year as expected.

I'm not want to degradation of performance technique as much as possible, what are the workarounds?
I am considering muscular strength training by its own weight so as not to drop the minimum necessary muscle strength.

Please tell me if you have any other ideas.

Comment: If all else fails and you cannot physically practice to stay in shape, then consider ear training: It can be done with a smartphone and earphones.  It won't keep you physically in form, but at least it's musical learning.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explained why you can't play while you're on the trip, but I'll assume it's because it will be too loud.

If that's the case, consider a "silent" electric violin. The concept is the same as the electric guitar: minimal acoustic sound is amplified by electronic pickups. For performances, it is played through an amplifier/speaker system, but you can get a very small portable amplifier for your electric violin (there are many such devices for guitar, they would probably work just as well for violin) and play through headphones. I used to practice electric bass that way when I went to visit relatives:

Here are some informative videos about silent electric violins - there is plenty of material out there:

Here's what they call a "plug amp", designed for guitar. (I have one for bass):
[***Vox amPlug 2 Clean Headphone Guitar Amp***](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/amPlugCleanG2--vox-amplug-2-clean-headphone-guitar-amp)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

When I can't play, I keep my hands and arms in shape by using a medium sized soft rubber ball. I squeeze it repeatedly until my hand feels strained, and then change hands and do it again. That takes care of the hands. Musically I can look at the music and imagine myself actually performing the piece as I read the music, this goes a long way towards keeping the music fresh in my mind. When you think about it, you see that is what you're doing when you are actually playing your fiddle.